# Swap the first two element of a list, (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, syntax-error, swap

In order to swap the first two elements of a list, I've written the following code:

```
swap_first_two_elements :: [a]->[a]
swap_first_two_elements list=case list of
  x:y:_ -> y:x:_
  [x] -> Nothing
  []-> Nothing
```

However, the terminal shows the error shown below:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )

test.hs:3:16: Pattern syntax in expression context: _
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude>
```

Who likes to tell me what is wrong with it?

Btw, ive also tried to combine the last two row into:

```
[x] || [] ->Nothing
```

How is it wrong?  Terminal shows:

```
test.hs:4:3: Parse error in pattern: [x] || []
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Who likes to tell me what is wrong with it? Thanks XD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The mistake is that you cannot use `_` in the result of a branch.  `_` is reserved to indicate an unused variable.  If you want to reuse the tail of the list, you must bind it to another name:

```
swap_first_two_elements :: [a]->[a]
swap_first_two_elements list = case list of
  x:y:xs -> y:x:xs
  [x]    -> Nothing
  []     -> Nothing
```

However, if you compile that you will get another error.  Your case branches return values of different types.  The first branch returns a value of type `[a]`, but your second and third branch return a value of type `Maybe [a]`.  To fix it, you have to wrap the first branch in a `Just` (and also fix your type signature to indicate that you are returning `Maybe [a]` and not `[a]`):

```
swap_first_two_elements :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
swap_first_two_elements list = case list of
  x:y:xs -> Just (y:x:xs)
  [x]    -> Nothing
  []     -> Nothing
```

The last improvement is that you can combine your last two case branches into one by using the fallback pattern match on everything:

```
swap_first_two_elements :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
swap_first_two_elements list = case list of
  x:y:xs -> Just (y:x:xs)
  _      -> Nothing
```

Comment: Thx man, i've fixed my mistake and change Nothing to error"XXX", so everything is fixed, thank u so much XDD

Comment: You're welcome!  I recommend you try out the `Maybe` approach later on.  Haskell has lots of nice tools for working with values wrapped inside `Maybe`s, so you don't lose anything by keeping it.

Comment: Btw, last question to ask, since u have left "_ -> Nothing" in the end of ur last piece of code, is it because Haskell's rule of order let x:y:xs go before "_->Nothing"??, So that '_->nothing' will not include  the case 'x:y:xs'  anymore?

Comment: yea, but the requirement from my exercise is to write a function use this profile:   sfte::[a]->[a]

Comment: then, instead of returning Nothing, you can for example return the empty list, or the one-element-list

Comment: @libra Yes, case statements always match from top to bottom, so the second branch won't match if the first branch matches.

Comment: @kaan is correct: This code should never call `error`. Instead define the function in such a way as to always return a valid result. In this case just end with: `xs -> xs` (note that this `xs` will be different than the one above. Think of it this way: Rather than the function being "swap the first two elements of the list, and crash and burn if there aren't that many", define it as "swap the first two elements of the list, if they are two"

Comment: @MtnViewMark, Sry, im a little bit confused, Did u mean let the rest of possible list excluding "x:y:xs" to return the same result?

Comment: @MtnViewMark, lol, I think i get it, great idea btw, might be helpful XD